# Raspberry Pi Wifi hotspot without DNS resolution

Tags: wifi, dns

Have set up a wireless hotspot using hostapd and a Realtek dongle. The hotspot is created fine, devices can connect, however all DNS resolution by clients fails. I believe this is due to the network the Pi is connected to blocks them, and forces clients to use its own internal resolvers.

Is there a way to set up a hotspot such that DNS resolution is done by internal servers?
I have tried setting them in /etc/network/interfaces for the wireless adapter however this has not worked.

Comment: What are you looking for? DNS for other devices on the LAN? Then the DNS MUST point to the DHCP! If DNS for Internet fails then set the DNS on the hotspot to `8.8.8.8` (although LAN DNS will NOT work with this!)

Comment: I need all wifi clients to use the same DNS as the eth0 interface. eth0 uses a dynamic address provided by an external (to me) DHCP server. Using any other resolvers will fail as the requests are blocked by the network eth0 (internet provider) is connected to.

Comment: To get everything forced to eth0 try adding default route making all traffic from wlan0's IP to eth0. I think it should be something like this or similiar.